# Python BeautifulSoup Parsing Script Tags

Tags: python, regex, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to parse the contents within a script tag to extract certain data. The following code uses a valid xbox live account.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

email = 'email'
password = 'password'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(r'https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&rver=6.7.6643.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https:%2f%2faccount.xbox.com%2fen-us%2faccountcreation%3freturnUrl%3dhttps:%252f%252fwww.xbox.com:443%252fen-US%252f%26pcexp%3dtrue%26uictx%3dme%26rtc%3d1&lc=1033&id=292543&aadredir=1')
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="i0116"] """).send_keys(email)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="idSIButton9"] """).click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="i0118"] """).send_keys(password)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="idSIButton9"] """).click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.get(r'https://account.xbox.com/en-us/Friends?xr=mebarnav&rtc=1')
print('Grabbing Cookies')
time.sleep(5)


headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36'}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

for cookie in driver.get_cookies():
    c = {cookie['name'] : cookie['value']}
    s.cookies.update(c)

#s.get('https://account.xbox.com/en-us/Friends?xr=mebarnav&rtc=1')


soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get('https://account.xbox.com/en-us/Profile?xr=mebarnav&activetab=tertiary:friendsTab&rtc=1').content, 'html.parser')

text = str(soup.find_all('script')[13])

value = re.findall(r'DisplayName', text)

print(value)
```

I am trying to access the certain data that comes after each "DisplayName" but I am failing to do so as I am just getting "DisplayName" instead of its value. If you need a better idea, you can print the "text" variable and search for "DisplayName". Thanks to all of those who reply in advance.

Comment: Copy the display name code and paste it here. You're getting the display name with `re` but nothing behind it. Send the code and I'll help you fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason you're not getting anything is because you're telling `re` to search for the exact phrase. You're not telling it to get any more characters and where to stop. In the example below I am using single quotes but the code could be adjusted for double quotes. I then have `re` find the DisplayName but the `.*` find the characters behind it but stop at the single quote '. Then after that it's just replacing the stuff you don't want.

```
import re

url = "DisplayName='PoppaBear4'"

info = re.findall(r"DisplayName=.*'", url)
print(str(info).replace("DisplayName='",'').replace("'","").replace('["','').replace('"]',''))
```